# How to deal with a dependency Property that is already registered

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls, dependency-properties

I have a DependencyProperty declared like so;

```
    Public ReadOnly ShowHideAddButtonProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHideAddButton", GetType(Boolean), GetType(DataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(True, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnShowHideAddButtonChanged)))
```

It forms part of a standalone UserControl that I'm building (both because it will be useful to me in the future and because it's a good way to learn).  When the control is first added to a project and that project is run it works well, thereafter it throws an ArguementException with a message stating that 'ShowHideAddButton' property was already registered by 'MyControl'.

So as one does I started looking up the possibility of Unregistering the dependency property but it would appear that this is not a good idea. Two questions arise from this.

To add further clarity, in the light of the answer below here is the full code relating to the dependency property.  Making the method Shared causes 'ShowHideAddButton' and 'Add' to throw the same error as mentioned in my comment to the answer.

```
Public Shared ReadOnly ShowHideAddButtonProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHideAddButton", GetType(Boolean), GetType(DataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(True, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnShowHideAddButtonChanged)))

'''////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
''' <summary>
''' Gets or sets a value indicating whether the hide add button is shown.
''' </summary>
'''
''' <value> true if show hide add button, false if not. </value>
'''////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<Description("Set the visibility of the Add button on the Navigator Control"), Category("Navigator Buttons Visibility")>
Public Property ShowHideAddButton As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(GetValue(ShowHideAddButtonProperty))
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        SetValue(ShowHideAddButtonProperty, value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Shared Sub OnShowHideAddButtonChanged()
    If ShowHideAddButton = True Then 'this now throws an error as well as Add below
        Add.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Visible 'Add being the button whose visibility is to be changed
    Else
        Add.Visibility = Windows.Visibility.Collapsed
    End If

End Sub
```

1) why is this error occurring in the first place...presumably it's an error in my original code, but as it compiles without error I'm not sure what it might be?

2) Is it sufficient to simply wrap the offending line in a try Catch block to catch the offending error  which is probably doable but doesn't really solve the problem or inform me as to why it's happening in the first place.

Some additional info:

The actual Control looks not unlike this:
[image]

It is comprised of a number of separate buttons and textboxes, and in the case of this problem the DependencyProperty ShowHideAddButton is a property of the DataNavigator Control but it needs to trigger the visibility of the Button named AddButton in the control.  My problem is trying to figure out how to refer to that button.

Thanks

Comment: No.  There are five similar properties (but with different names), and I have run through the code with a fine toothcomb to make sure it isn't a duplication.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new dependency property you declared shall be static (shared in VB.Net): `Public Shared ReadOnly ShowHideAddButtonProperty As DependencyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowHideAddButton", GetType(Boolean), GetType(DataNavigator), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(True, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender, New PropertyChangedCallback(AddressOf OnShowHideAddButtonChanged)))`
Check this out: [DependencyProperty Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3)

The PropertyChangedCallback needs to be changed to PropertyMetadata in the DependencyProperty.Register.
Then the OnShowHideAddButtonChanged method's paramter signature needs to be changed to `(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs eventArgs).` Finally, in that method, you can reach your control like this `var control = dependecyObject as YourControl.` Therefore you can reach the instance fields, properties and methods in the static method.

Comment: Thanks,  Is that the sole reason why this would happen?  I ask because if I make it a shared Property it then shows a copile error under the part of the Declarion (AddressOf OnShowHideAddButtonChanged) pointing out that you cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initialiser without an explicit instance of a class.  This is a user control that will be dragged from the toolbox typically, it has a constructor but I can see people specifically instantiating it.  Clearly I'm missing the point somewhere but not sure where.

Comment: Yes, the OnShowHideAddButtonChanged method needs to be shared as well becaouse the its Depenecy Property is shared.

Comment: Well I think that you're correct, so +1 there) But in making the method shared it throws similar errors because it's referes to other parts of the class.  I guess this means that I need to rethink the original declaration of the DependencyProperty.  For the sake of clarity I've added all of the code for the related parts in my Original question.

Comment: Well, as far as I can tell, the problem is OnShowHideAddButtonChanged method refers to non-shared property (ShowHideAddButton). In the DepenendecyProperty.Register, you should change the PropertyChangedCallback to PropertyMetadata. I've edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @DomSinclair The PropertyChangedCallback method has to be shared, but you can cast the first argument (of type DependencyObject) to the current instance of your control, that the property was set on. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertychangedcallback.aspx).

Comment: @Clemens Thank you.  As is so very often the case I understand two thirds of this but not the last third (or in short the key bit to make it work.  I have added some more detail to the original question and now I need to try and figure out how to refer to the actual button I want to change.